# Why don't colors change in matplotlib boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I make a boxplot with matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = pd.DataFrame([54.183933149245775,98.14228839908178,97.56790596547185,81.28351460722497,116.36733517668105,93.64706288367272,107.68860349692736,109.65565349602194,88.58717530217115,54.87561132504807,137.89097514410435,116.90021701471281,121.41252555476005,102.68420408219474,107.32642696333856,
 120.27307064490907,114.3674635060443,91.38936314166017,149.0476109186976,121.76625219213736,155.6027360469248,115.86331915425764,99.35036421024546,104.93804853361358,115.64286896238708,129.51583078514085,116.30239399660411,97.58582728510798,119.59975852978403,103.68594428632996], columns=['A'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
A.boxplot(grid=False, fontsize=12, notch=True,
            flierprops = dict(markersize=10, markeredgecolor ='red', markerfacecolor='b'),
            boxprops = dict(linewidth=2, color='red'))
fig.show()
```

[image]

The flier props will change the colors and marker size. However, for "boxprops", the linewidth can change but the color NEVER changes (here it stays blue). Does anybody know why? Also, where is the matplotlib documentation giving all the options for these properties?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by doing two things actually,

- First, determine the `return_type` of your `boxplot`
- Second, change the color of the `boxes key` like so:

Here, I will change the boxes into green

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = pd.DataFrame([54.183933149245775,98.14228839908178,97.56790596547185,81.28351460722497,116.36733517668105,93.64706288367272,107.68860349692736,109.65565349602194,88.58717530217115,54.87561132504807,137.89097514410435,116.90021701471281,121.41252555476005,102.68420408219474,107.32642696333856,
 120.27307064490907,114.3674635060443,91.38936314166017,149.0476109186976,121.76625219213736,155.6027360469248,115.86331915425764,99.35036421024546,104.93804853361358,115.64286896238708,129.51583078514085,116.30239399660411,97.58582728510798,119.59975852978403,103.68594428632996], columns=['A'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
bp = A.boxplot(grid=False, fontsize=12, notch=True,
               flierprops = dict(markersize=10, markeredgecolor ='red', markerfacecolor='b'),
                boxprops = dict(linewidth=2, color='red'),
                return_type='dict')  # add this argument

# set the color of the boxes to green
for item in bp['boxes']:
    item.set_color('g')
plt.show()
```

And this will show the following graph:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know where the documentation for other options are? I would like to change other elements. The documentation I found makes no mention of 'set_color'.

Comment: I didn't know that from the documentation actually, I knew elsewhere. You can do the same with `'whiskers'`, `'caps'`, `'medians'`, `'fliers'`, and `'means'`.

Comment: @user3329732 `bp` is a dictionary containing the matplotlib [Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html) objects of each boxplot element (where you will find `set_color`). [Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html) is the matplotlib boxplot docs, in the return section it tells you what the contents of the dictionary are

Comment: @DavidG I don't see how those docs solve my problem - I did already find them. Personally, I find them shockingly inadequate.

Comment: @user3329732 They don't solve your problem, this answer does. I was just answering your questions of what/where `set_color` comes from, and where the documentation of the contents of the dictionary can be found

Comment: @DavidG I wasn't complaining at you - I think the docs are arcane and are an exercise in poor communication